# How to get a 3D accordion effect on Android

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, 3d, accordion

I am planning to port the great 3D accordion effect found on iOS (https://github.com/xyfeng/XYOrigami) on Android.

so far I have something pretty close, here is a screenshot with "pinch-to-fold" to fold the view:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/3daccordion.png

as you can see, it remains a space between 2 opposite "panels".
The process is simple:

1. take the canvas of the main Layout
2. create a Custom surface view which will replace all the view of the layout
3. set as background image the taken canvas
4. cut this canvas into X panels (here 16)
5. redraw the surfaceview with all the "panels" with a calculated matrix
6. recalculate the matrix while pinching to give the "folding effect"

here is the transformation matrix :

```
private Matrix getFoldingMatrix(int angle, int startFrom,int position) {
    int move = (int) (
        (mWidth - (Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * mWidth)) * position
    ) +1*position; //overlap of 1px the panels and not get space between panels

    final Camera camera = new Camera();
    final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    camera.save();

    camera.rotateY(angle);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);

    if(position%2==1){
        move += (int) (
            (mWidth - (Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * mWidth))
        ) ;
        matrix.preTranslate(-mWidth, -mHeight/2);
        matrix.postTranslate(startFrom+mWidth-move, mHeight/2);
    } else {
        matrix.preTranslate(0f, -mHeight/2);
        matrix.postTranslate(startFrom-move, mHeight/2);
    }
    camera.restore();

    return matrix;
}
```

what am I getting wrong ? why is there still these spaces between opposite "panels"?

Comment: it might be because of the perspective, since this "space" is not linear and is then linked to the rotation angle.

Comment: Have you got the code in github or somewhere?